# How to make a PHP template without a database?

Tags: php, templates, directory-structure

I'm working on a small company "brochure" website. I have a few pieces that repeat for example:

- Menu
- Submenu
- Footer
- Subheader

Say a page "comparison.php" needs to have all of the above and then content. I could do which is how I started:

```html
<?php include '/partial/menu.php'; ?>

<p>This is a product comparison</p>
<figure>
  <figcaption>Probably an image here</figcaption>
  ((image))
</figure>
<table>
  <tr><td>Product 1</td><td>Product 2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Point A</td><td>Point B</td></tr>
</table>

<?php include '/partial/footer.php'; ?>
```

I'm thinking what a better way might be. Perhaps adding a directory `content` so then it becomes:

```html
<?php include '/partial/menu.php'; ?>

<?php include '/content/comparison.php'; ?>

<?php include '/partial/footer.php'; ?>
```

This still feels clunky to me especially when I've got multiple subheaders and submenus depending on the page.

I've read online about templates with PHP but everything is with databases just inserting variables like, [Programmers.SE - How to structure template system using plain PHP](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159529/how-to-structure-template-system-using-plain-php)  How would I go about streamlining this as much as possible without using a database? And please do not tell me to use a CMS, it's not an option.

Comment: you don't NEED a database, but most sites are driven by a db, hence most tutorials talking about them. php won't care where/how you get your data.

Comment: @MarcB I'm not sure what your point is in relation to how I should structure this.

Comment: If CMS isn't an option, what about a framework like Laravel? http://laravel.com/ I've used it in a similar way to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @mopo922 no frameworks, no CMS. Just need to understand the methodology and practice so I can do it by hand.

Comment: Does your question not suposse to be: how to make a content loader with php?

Comment: @Fleuv -- I have no idea, is that what I should be searching for? Never heard the term.

Comment: @Ryan, well its worth a try, but nope it's not a term. The term for this would be something like: templating or theming.

Comment: May be you do single-page site? You wont even need PHP pages if you don't have dinamic data.

Comment: @cybersoft No it needs to be multiple pages. There's way too much information for a single page solution.

Comment: May be again, you didn't understand: single-page means that you have one html page with scripts which generates all content in page

Comment: @cybersoft do you have a tutorial explaining this process I could look at?

Comment: No, I haven't, but you can read definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), and an example of [singe-page site](http://www.usatoday.com/) from Backbone homepage, which can be used to build such sites.

Comment: @cybersoft thanks I'll look into it. I think I figured out a solution though (left it as an answer)

Comment: @cybersoft The example single-page site is also a content loader, it looks like this one is build with AJAX.

Comment: @Fleuv AJAX is a heart of such sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright I think I figured out a methodology that is quite nice.

3 Main Files being used:

1. comparison.php
2. information_template.php
3. content/comparison.php

**comparison.php**

```html
<?php
$pagename = 'comparison';

include('information_template.php');
?>
```

**information_template.php**

```html
<?php include '/content/' . $pagename . '.php'; ?>
```

**content/comparison.php**

> All of the content goes here

Now I can just make a page in my root and a page in the content for each one with the same format and it should work. I'll probably add some additional to **comp.php** something like `$pagetype = 'information';` or `$pagetype = 'review';` so I can then add to my **information_template.php**:

```html
<?php include '/partial/' . $pagetype . '-subheader.php'; ?>
<?php include '/partial/' . $pagetype . '-toc.php'; ?>
```